# Can't find file and I don't know how to find it (macbook)

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

This is the code that was written using a youtube tutorial. However, the program can't seem to find the image even though the image was saved in the same file if that makes sense. Please help.

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime

app= customtkinter.CTk()
app.title('Annie\'s Burmese Bar')
app.geometry("1000x780")
app.config(bg="White")
app.resizable(False,False)

font1=('Times New Roman', 40 ,'bold')
font2=('Times New Roman', 15 ,'bold')
font3=('Times New Roman', 12 ,'bold')
price_list=[50,30,25]
total_price=0

bill_frame= customtkinter.CTkFrame(app, width=300, height=1000, fg_color= "Pink")
bill_frame.place(x=700,y=0)

menu_label=customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text= "Annie\'s Burmese Bar", font= font1, text_color="White", bg_color="Pink")
menu_label.place(x=230, y=5)

img1=PhotoImage(file="App1.png")

img1_label=customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image=img1, text="Fermented Tea Leaves Salad\n A refreshing and tangy salad with fermented tea leaves. \n Price: $8.50",font=font2, text_color="Black", fg_color="Pink", width=200, height=200, corner_radius=20, compund= TOP,anchor=N)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happens when you run this?  If there is an error, please include the full traceback error.

Comment: _even though the image was saved in the same file_ Do you mean the same **directory**?

Comment: yes my bad TT....

Comment: What's a *"TT"* please? Also, if you know there's an error in your question, please click [edit] and correct it. Try `print(os.getcwd())` to see where your program is looking for the *"lost"* file.

Comment: I got it to work now no worries anymore thank you!